# When global login fail report shows no test results

Tags: automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

So I have created a global setup file for login and I have added monocart as a reports so what happens if the logins fails the other test cases doesn't run it shows 0 test cases and if we open report it shows no test results. Any idea what could have been wrong?

I need to fail all the test cases if the login test case in global setup fails.

Comment: Please share all the relevant code per the discussion to have some meaningful answers.